# Resolve local file path from Twig template name

Tags: symfony, twig

What are the programmatic steps to turn this string:

```
AcmeProjectBundle::home.html.twig
```

into this?

```
/path/Symfony/src/Acme/ProjectBundle/Resources/views/home.html.twig
```

Comment: Are you asking for the algorithm used?  Or for an actual function you can call?  Keep in mind that this is all done during the "compile" phase with the results stored in the cache.  Not something that you would normally deal with during run time.

Comment: The functions used within twig/symfony.

Comment: See Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateNameParser

Comment: hmm, vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/Loader/TemplateLocator.php looks promising

Comment: Can I access the Kernel object from a controller, or at least something that can lead me to it?

Comment: @carlosz is right. TemplateNameParser is the class. However you can't view any value on the file because the class is cached at app/cache/[env]/classes.php and loaded from there.

Comment: Check

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585474/accessing-files-relative-to-bundle-in-symfony2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to retrieve path from a controller you can use this code:

```php
$parser = $this->container->get('templating.name_parser');
$locator = $this->container->get('templating.locator');

$path = $locator->locate($parser->parse('AcmeProjectBundle::home.html.twig'));
```

For more info take a look at code of:

- `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateNameParser::parse`
- `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator::locate`

Answer (score 0):

*(To expand the answer of Molecular Man)*

For the people needing this in **Symfony 4**:

The service `templating.name_parser` is not registered as such by default anymore and you need the dependency `symfony/templating` in Composer for it to be usable.
Also, it's recommended now to not use the container directly to get services (not to mention that the new AbstractController doesn't have all the services available), but rather do Dependency Injection by type-hinting.

So, the way to get it to work with Symfony 4:

```
//...
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateNameParser;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    public function indexAction(TemplateNameParser $parser, TemplateLocator $locator)
    {
        $path = $locator->locate($parser->parse('AcmeProjectBundle::home.html.twig'));
        //...
    }
}
```