# Convert Bundle:Controller:Filename to actual file path

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to convert Symfony filename notation `Bundle:Controller:Filename` to a real file path `/var/www/whatever/src/Bundle/Resources/views/Controller/Filename`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolve local file path from Twig template name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330170/resolve-local-file-path-from-twig-template-name)

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might find this useful as well: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tak a look at this question: [Resolve local file path from Twig template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330170/resolve-local-file-path-from-twig-template-name) . Accepted answer says:

"If you want to retrieve path from a controller you can use this code:

```
$parser = $this->container->get('templating.name_parser');
$locator = $this->container->get('templating.locator');

$path = $locator->locate($parser->parse('AcmeProjectBundle::home.html.twig'));
```

For more info take a look at code of:

```
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateNameParser::parse
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\TemplateLocator::locate
```

"

Comment: I knew I saw this somewhere before... Only the word "resolve" didn't come to my mind. Thanks!