# accessing resource file in vendors bundle

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony2 bundle which contains some wsdl files in Resources directory. It forces me to define some additional entries in config file like:

```
parameters.fx_wsdl = '../vendor/project-name/bundleName-bundle/vendorName/xxxBundle/Resources/confid/ws/fx.wsdl'
```

yeach, as you see it looks ugly. Is there a way to define it as:

```
parameters.fx_wsdl = 'VendorNameBundleNameBundle/Resources/confid/ws/fx.wsdl'
```

any object which can translate VendorNameBundleNameBundle into ../vendor/project-name/bundleName-bundle/vendorName/xxxBundle automatically

Comment: There's an example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585474