# symfony2 render php return contains invalid characters

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to render a php file in symfony2.

In config.yml I'm using:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    templating:    { engines: ['twig', 'php'] }
```

and in the Controller:

```
public function installAction($name) {
        $finder = new Finder();
        $finder->files()->in('../src/Admin/ModuleBundle/Modules/'.$name.'/')->directories();
        foreach ($finder as $file) {
            return $this->render($file.'/install.php');
        }}
```

but I got this error:
Template name "../src/Admin/ModuleBundle/Modules/Module1/config/install.php" contains invalid characters.

and the content of the file:

```
< ?php echo "Module1 install";
```

what I'm doing wrong?
the php file is just a simple echo

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7587106) SO Answer help you out?

Comment: ...and also **have a look at the [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html)** if you haven't yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
< ?php echo "Module1 install";
 ^
```

This space. **EDIT** In fact, having a look at the internals, it seems that this line:

```
if (false !== strpos($name, '..')) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Template name "%s" contains invalid characters.', $name));
}
```

(from [this file](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Templating/TemplateNameParser.php)) would suggest that your path cannot have relative paths that go up a level in the directory tree.

Comment: Looks like someone needs more _Coffee_ ^^

Comment: this space was because stackoverflow wasn't recognizing the text

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, can you explain me better, thank you

Comment: @BrunoRamalho, basically, don't use `..`'s in the name of your path

Comment: so what else can I use? because i need to go one level back and then go inside Modules/name/config/install.php

Comment: so im using the realpath function. but still the same