# SplFileObject error failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, symfony, path, filepath, passbook

i am trying to implement passbook web service in symfony2 and following this [passbook bundle](https://github.com/eymengunay/PassbookBundle) and my controller looks like this

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Create an event ticket
        $pass = new EventTicket("1234567890", "The Beat Goes On");
        $pass->setBackgroundColor('rgb(60, 65, 76)');
        $pass->setLogoText('Apple Inc.');

        // Create pass structure
        $structure = new Structure();

        // Add primary field
        $primary = new Field('event', 'The Beat Goes On');
        $primary->setLabel('Event');
        $structure->addPrimaryField($primary);

        // Add secondary field
        $secondary = new Field('location', 'Moscone West');
        $secondary->setLabel('Location');
        $structure->addSecondaryField($secondary);

        // Add auxiliary field
        $auxiliary = new Field('datetime', '2013-04-15 @10:25');
        $auxiliary->setLabel('Date & Time');
        $structure->addAuxiliaryField($auxiliary);

        // Add icon image
        $icon = new Image('appassBundle/Resources/Images/icon.png', 'icon');
        $pass->addImage($icon);

        // Set pass structure
        $pass->setStructure($structure);

        // Add barcode
        $barcode = new Barcode(Barcode::TYPE_QR, 'barcodeMessage');
        $pass->setBarcode($barcode);

        // Create pass factory instance
        $factory = new PassFactory('pass.dk.mcoupons.mcoupon', '9W6X83AQ63', 'KA Innovation ApS', '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/certificates/certificate.p12', 'hestmink09', '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/certificates/applewwdrca.pem');
        $factory->setOutputPath('%kernel.root_dir%/logs/pkpass');
        $factory->package($pass);
        //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        //$em->persist($task);
        //$em->flush();
        echo 'pass generated ';
        return $this->render('apbappassBundle:Default:index.html.twig');

    }
```

but it is giving me this error

> SplFileObject::__construct(appassBundle/Resources/Images/icon.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException

i have tried different ways to give the path but failed. 
here is the hierarchy or folder structure where my images are stored

[image: folder structure]

Comment: apbappassBundle.php is in the appassBundle folder, so the relative path should be Resources/Images/icon.php

Comment: now it is giving me this error SplFileObject::__construct(Resources/Images/icon.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the path to the file containing the above code.

Comment: Does it have the necessary permissions to access that file?

Comment: tomas i tried to set permissions but was unable to do so.you see i am quite new to this platform . anyways problem already got solved thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $icon = new Image('%kernel.root_dir%/appassBundle/Resources/Images/icon.png', 'icon');
```

Or maybe:

```
$iconPath = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/appassBundle/Resources/Images/icon.png';
$icon = new Image($iconPath, 'icon');
```

Or similar, I don't see whole structure of your project.

Comment: this is exactly what i did and it fixed my problem but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Problem

The error tells it all. It means your `Image` object tries to instanciate an [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/splfileobject) under the hood.
Since the file you given does not exists, `SplFileObject::__construct()` [throws an exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.construct.php#refsect1-splfileobject.construct-errors) which is the one you're getting.

## Fix

Relative paths can easily be a nightmare, CLI SAPI et al. can mess everything. The simple fix is to use an ABSOLUTE path. I see two ways to handle it.

### Absolute path relative to the current file

In order to get the current absolute path, you can use the [`__DIR__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant. Here's an example of usage

```
// apb/appassBundle/Controller/BarController::fooAction


$iconPath = sprintf("%s/../Resources/Images/icon.png", __DIR__);
$icon = new Image($iconPath, "icon");
```

`$iconPath` now contains the absolute path to your icon. E.g:

```
/path/to/project/src/apb/appassBundle/Controller/../Resources/Images/icon.png
```

Which is correct, and the file actually exists.

### Absolute path relative to the bundle

Another way is to get the path stored in the bundle. [`BundleInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Bundle/BundleInterface.html) has a `getPath()` method which returns the absolute path of the bundle. (Root directory of the bundle)

```
// apb/appassBundle/Controller/BarController::fooAction

$bundle = $this->get('kernel')->getBundle('apbappassBundle');
$iconPath = sprintf("%s/Resources/Images/icon.png", $bundle->getPath());

$icon = new Image($iconPath, "icon");
```

`$iconPath` now contains something like

```
/path/to/project/src/apb/appassBundle/Resources/Images/icon.png
```

Which is also correct

---

> Edit 17/07/2014

As [mentionned by gilden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7587106/1607098), an alternative would be to use the method [**KernelInterface::locateResource**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.5.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/KernelInterface.php#L125)
You can use it like this

```
$iconPath = $this->get('kernel')->locateResource('@apbappassBundle/Resources/Images/icon.png');
$icon = new Image($iconPath, "icon");
```

Comment: thanx for the answer appreciated