# Symfony2: How restrict files in publicly accessible directory

Tags: symfony, authentication

I have XML files in a publicly accessible directory. I want to restrict them to accessible only to logged in users. So when I go to `http://example.com/web/file.xml` only AUTHENTICATED members can access the file. I'm using PHP & Symfony2.

Answer (score 1):

Files in web are all public so don't put it into that folder.

You can create a folder into Ressources and put your xml into it.

Then create an action witch read and display your file. In this way you will be able to secure your action.

For exemple you can access as http://monsite.com/xml/get

How to secure : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/securing_services.html

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with this

```
 $filename = $this->get('kernel')->locateResource("@SomeBundle/Resources/folder/‌file.xml");
```

([Accessing Files Relative to Bundle in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585474/accessing-files-relative-to-bundle-in-symfony2))