# Symfony2 How to get the Web or MyBundle directory from inside a controller?

Tags: symfony

`Symfony2`. In a `controller`, I would like to define a path to the `Resources/public/pdf` directory of a bundle of mine.

If I use `__DIR__`,  I get the path to the Controller directory of my bundle; if  `$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir()`, the path to the App directory. Either way I am not able to move back to the upper directory.

How do I do?

ps. something like `$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../src/` renders `.../app/../src/`.

EDIT I got what i need by a very simple minded and ugly fix:

```
$path001 = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/';
$path002 = explode('/', $path001);
$path003 = array_pop($path002);
$path003bis = array_pop($path002);
$path004 = implode("/", $path002);
$path_pdf  = $path004.'/src/Mario/<MyBundle>/Bundle/Resources/public/pdf';
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The realpath function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) can clean up all the dot dot stuff if it bothers you.

```
// From a controller
$resourceDir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../Resources');
```

Of course this only works if the controller is in a fixed directory and never moves.

I like to set a parameter using the dependency injection extension.

```
class CeradProjectExtension extends Extension
{
  public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
  {
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $container->setParameter(
      'sportacus_project_resources_dir',
      realpath(__DIR__ . '/../Resources')
    );
```

The path can be injected or retrieved from the container.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is:

```
$kernel = $this->container->getService('kernel');
$path = $kernel->locateResource('@MarioMyBundle/Resources/public/pdf/file.pdf');
```

as per [Accessing Files Relative to Bundle in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585474/accessing-files-relative-to-bundle-in-symfony2)